# Change contents of a LinearLayout

Tags: android

Good morning people,

I am making an app and to the following problem !

Have an activity that has a LinearLayout and inside it has 3 buttons , I wanted to click on certain button , these three buttons vanished and within that LinearLayout enter another , with textview , other buttons and all, but when you click the button back android , back before the three buttons , all this without changing the top of the page , trying to do with Fragments , but to no avail ...

Answer (score 0):

Trying to manage this through visibility of different layout elements (i.e. LinearLayout) can lead to serviceability issue in the long term.

Fragments would be one of the better ways to implement this.

I personally have found the following tutorial about Fragment helpful as an introduction:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html